# Passing an empty prop (no api value) to react component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am passing data from an array to a react component. One of the values is empty and the object is quite rightfully undefined. I have tried one thing but in this setup does not work.... I am passing `personId` and `secondpersonId` to my profile component. If the person does not have a `secondpersonId` it creates an undefined.

```
<Profile person={{ 
personid: firstperson[0].personId,
secondpersonid: secondperson[0].secondpersonId,
}} />
```

I have tried this for the secondpersonId...

```
<Profile person={{ 
personid: firstperson[0].personId,
secondpersonid: (secondperson[0].secondpersonId || 'No id'),
}} />
```

But it still complains that it cannot read property of undefined. Its the array of `secondperson[0]` that does not exist.

Comment: You should be doing the check on `secondperson` not `secondpersonId`

Comment: Try `secondperson ? secondperson[0].secondpersonId : 'No id'`

Comment: Are both `secondperson` and `secondperson[0]` both defined? (Otherwise `secondperson[0].secondpersonId` cannot be evaluated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) operator like this :

```
<Profile person={{ 
personid: firstperson[0].personId,
secondpersonid: ((secondperson && secondperson[0]) ? secondperson[0].secondpersonId : 'No id'),
}} />
```

Comment: Props for checking both the var and index existence

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you need to check for secondperson

```
secondpersonid: (secondperson ? secondperson[0].secondpersonId : 'No id'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JS's [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like this:

```
<Profile person={{ 
  personid: firstperson[0].personId,
  secondpersonid: (secondperson[0] ? secondperson[0].secondpersonId : 'No id'),
}} />
```

OR, you can harness the power of JS's [Logical AND(`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) and [Logical OR(`||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) operator like this:

```
<Profile person={{ 
  personid: firstperson[0].personId,
  secondpersonid: (secondperson[0] && secondperson[0].secondpersonId) || 'No id'),
}} />
```

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, your ternary says if `secondperson[0]` exists, then assign string `'No id'`, and if it doesn't exist use `secondperson[0].secondpersonId`  wrong way around

Comment: @DarrenSweeney damn! my bad